# Submeter apenas um elemento de dois com mesmo name

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho um `form`, e neste tenho que informar o bairro, porém o elemento que armazena a informação do bairro pode variar de acordo com o valor da cidade selecionada anteriormente.

**Exemplo:**

Se a cidade for "principal" deve mudar devo mudar o campo bairro de um `input` para um `select`. Consegui fazer a troca assim:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('bairro') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="bairro" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bairro</label>

    <div id="bairro-select" class="col-sm-10" hidden>
        <select class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro">
            <option value="" selected>--- Escolha um bairro ---</option>
            @foreach($bairros as $bairro)
                <option value="{{ $bairro->nome }}">{{$bairro->nome}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="bairro-input" class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro" placeholder="" minlength="3" maxlength="90">
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#cidade").on('change', function() {
    var cidade = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    if(cidade == 'Principal') {
        bairroselect.style.display = "block";
        bairroinput.style.display = "none";
    }else {
        bairroselect.style.display = "none";
        bairroinput.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

Porém quando vou enviar o `form` no `request` o `bairro` fica sempre com o conteúdo do `input`, mesmo que selecionando um `bairro` no `select` este pega o valor do `input`.

O código que fiz deixa a `div` apenas oculta o elemento. Como poderia fazer para que apenas o valor que é exibido seja submetido?

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e incluior o código de como você faz os request, pois cada elemento tem um `name`, como você valida qual deve utilizar no `PHP`?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero desculpe estava fazendo um teste e nem vi que foi o código errado

Comment: A questão é justamente os dois terem o mesmo nome, fiz uam gambi que mando com nomes diferentes e verifico no controller qual não é null, porém acredito que deva ter alguma forma melhor

Comment: @CaiqueRomero mas dai não poderei usar ?

Comment: Veja se minha resposta te ajuda.

Comment: Teste porém o código não funciona para deixar o campo `disabled`

Comment: Consegui, o problema é que o id ali era o da `div`, tive que atribuir o do `select` e do `input` mesmo, mas valeu mesmo ajudou muito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione a propriedade `disabled` em um deles antes do submit.

**Segue exemplo similar ao seu:**

```js
$("#cidade").on('change', function() {
    var cidade = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    if(cidade == 'Principal') {
        $("#bairro-select").css("display","block");
        $("#bairro-select").prop("disabled", false);
        
        $("#bairro-input").css("display","none");
        $("#bairro-input").prop("disabled", true);
    }else {
        $("#bairro-select").css("display","none");
        $("#bairro-select").prop("disabled", true);
        
        $("#bairro-input").css("display","block");
        $("#bairro-input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cidade" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    Cidade
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
     <select class="form-control" name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option value="" selected>Escolha a cidade</option>
        <option value="Cidade1">Cidade1</option>
        <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
     </select>
  </div>
  <label for="bairro-select" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    Bairro
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro-select" style="display:none;">
       <option value="" selected>--- Escolha um bairro ---</option>
       <option value="Bairro1">Bairro 1</option>
       <option value="Bairro2">Bairro 2</option>
     </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
            name="bairro" id="bairro-input"   minlength="3" maxlength="90" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode remover o atributo `name` do elemento oculto, assim o PHP não vai *confundir* os dois elementos com o mesmo `name`, porque apenas um ou outro terá o atributo `name="bairro"`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#cidade").on('change', function() {
    var cidade = $(this).val();
    if(cidade == 'Principal') {
        $("#bairro-select")
        .show()
        .find("select")
        .attr("name","bairro");

        $("#bairro-input")
        .hide()
        .find("input")
        .attr("name","");
    }else {
        $("#bairro-select")
        .hide()
        .find("select")
        .attr("name","");

        $("#bairro-input")
        .show()
        .find("input")
        .attr("name","bairro");
    }
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cidade">
   <option value="...">Selecione</option>
   <option value="Bairro">Bairro</option>
   <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('bairro') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="bairro" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bairro</label>

    <div id="bairro-select" class="col-sm-10" hidden>
        <select class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro">
            <option value="" selected>--- Escolha um bairro ---</option>
            @foreach($bairros as $bairro)
                <option value="{{ $bairro->nome }}">{{$bairro->nome}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="bairro-input" class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro" placeholder="" minlength="3" maxlength="90">
    </div>

</div>
```